# How to map permalinks with accented letters to sanitized slugs?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, htaccess, mod-rewrite

To keep legacy entries on a blog hosted on TypePad on sync with a new WordPress installation...

How do I map this permalink with accented letters:

```
domain.com/no-es-fácil-alejarse-de-la-política
```

to this clean WP permalink without accented letter:

```
domain.com/no-es-facil-alejarse-de-la-politica
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is remove the default sanitize_title filter and replace it with yours, which will encode those characters properly. Here is an implementation of [using accents in permalinks](http://awordpress.net/blog/accents-in-wordpress-permalinks/).

Example:

```
remove_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes');
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'restore_raw_title', 9, 3 );
function sweURLtoCHAR($text)
{
  $url=array(
    "%C3%81","%C3%A1",
    "%C3%8D","%C3%AD"
  );
  $char=array(
     "Á","á",
     "Í","í"
  );

  $str = str_replace($char,$url,$text);
  $str_new = str_replace(" ", "", $str);
  return strtolower($str_new);
}
function restore_raw_title( $title, $raw_title, $context ) {
  if ( $context == 'save' )
   return sweURLtoCHAR($raw_title);
  else {
   $title_new = str_replace(" ", "", $title);
   return strtolower($title_new);
  }
}
```

You can find the characters and their utf8 hex [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) and build an array with the accented characters you need.

Comment: Can you provide a code example here?

Comment: Just edited and added an example code :)

Comment: Why do you need to change out sanitize_title?  According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title "and (in a 'save' context) accents are removed (accented characters are replaced with non-accented equivalents)".  So, if you can simply run sanitize_title with save contwext you get the slug without accents.  There is also a wordpress function remove_accents (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_accents)

Comment: Worked like a charm, but to make it work I changed sanitize_title_with_dashes with sanitize_title to write the url, not just the permalink slug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a redirection with .htacces or perhaps try out the wordpress plugin [redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/).

Comment: Thanks, but what would be the rewrite rule to be used on the .htaccess file? I'm redirecting thousands of posts.

Comment: No idea, i'm not an expert on the rewrite-rules myself.  You could check out the docs of the apache manual.