# International characters in slugs to redirect to

Tags: redirect, urls, slug

I would like to add special Hungarian characters to slug. Also in the slug of the post, and in taxonomy. . Eg "kér", "ács" etc.  This slug then applied also in the URL. Is this possible?

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: Yes. WP removes special characters. Eg. 'zér-zör' will be replaced with 'zer-zor'.

Comment: That's what I looked for: 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50533/how-to-map-permalinks-with-accented-letters-to-sanitized-slugs

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to store this type of slug.If you store this type of slug and after some time when you edit any item from wordpress back-end,then it will update with its own slug.Better way is to store your slug as wordpress store itself..

Comment: Because my intention that my webpage redirect to these slugs. These characters are normal in our languages. Eg. http://ár.hu/szúr/

Comment: you have one file from which you add this slug into table?

Comment: No. This should work as a normal slug. Eg. I write a post with a title: "Áron". WP should create the slug of the post : áron. The URL of my post should be: http://mydomain.hu/áron/

Comment: Ok.you add the data from WP back-end and it store with its own slug name.And right now your webpage is not redirect to your slug?

Comment: When I save post, WP rewrites my slug "áron" to "aron", and redirects to mydomain.hu/aron. But I want to save my slug:"áron" and redirect to mydomain.hu/áron

Comment: When you go for mydomain.hu/aron URL you cannot able to access the page?